# How to trigger add event listener of input with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

I want to auto fill an input area with javascript. When i fill it with organic key press, this input's event listener trigger another list which is releated what input is. But when i say:

```
document.getElementById('CardNumber').value = "123"
```

it does not trigger anything.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20Z2I.png)

So how can i trigger this "keyup" event listener?
Any suggestion is accepted.

Comment: you can trigger it with something like `$("#"+cardNumber).change();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `keyup` event-listener, you can raise `new Event("keyup")` by using `dispatchEvent` from the function where you are changing the value of element.

Reference - See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event).

```js
const element = document.getElementById('username');

element.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}, false);

function changeValue() {
  document.getElementById('username').value = '123';
  element.dispatchEvent(new Event("keyup"));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" />

<br />
<br />
<button onclick="changeValue()">Change value inside username</button>
```

Comment: You are my hero !!!

Comment: :) Moz has a very nice article to explain this! worth a read !  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can dispatch a `keyup` event whenever you are setting a new value yourself

```
const keyupEvent = new Event('keyup')
cardNumber.dispatchEvent(keyupEvent)
```

```js
// document.getElementById("CardNumber").value = "123"
const cardNumber = document.getElementById("CardNumber");
cardNumber.addEventListener("keyup", keupLister)

function keupLister(e) {
  console.log('keyup fired',e.target.value);
}

setTimeout(() => {
  cardNumber.value = "123";
  const keyupEvent = new Event('keyup')
  cardNumber.dispatchEvent(keyupEvent)
  
}, 5000)
```

```html
<input id="CardNumber" placeholder="Try this input">
```